# How to create a unique code to invite new users to a group in a mobile app

Tags: flutter, mobile, usergroups

I am building a mobile app with flutter and firebase.
I want to generate a unique id, es "453562" every time a new group of users is created, so new users will be invited to the group and can only access it through this code.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [uuid package](https://pub.dev/packages/uuid) (even though it is suposed to be used for ID keys, however it could work).

Answer (score -1):

To generate a unique ID to invite without collisions you can use this code

```dart
import 'package:id_gen/id_gen.dart';

final inviteId = UuidGen().get();         // string
final inviteId = UuidGen().get().hash();  // integer
```

from the lightweight and well-tested Dart package https://pub.dev/packages/id_gen